# How to create mapping of a field of type `Array`?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to create a index in `elasticsearch` with document having a field as `array`. Elasticsearch is giving error - `'reason': 'No type specified for field <field_name>'`.

I am giving like -`"field_name": {"store": "false"}`. I want this field to be of type Array of string.
But Elasticsearch does not support Array type - 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/array.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

> No type specified for field field_name

You simply need to define the type of data that is contained in your array.

```
"field_name": {
   "type": "text",          <--- add this
   "store": "false"
}
```

And then you can index an array of strings

```
{
   "field_name": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```